# How to preview variables in STL containers (e.g. std::map) in NetBeans in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, gdb

As I see, it's impossible to figure out what is in an STL map using NetBeans.

Is there any plugin/trick/solution that will allow me to print out all values from a map in debug mode?

As far as I know it's using GDB for debugging C++ applications. I've found some nice GDB macros for STL containers (here: http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2008-02/msg00064.html). Would it be possible to execute them from inside NetBeans?

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans uses `gdb` internally, so updating `gdb` to pretty-print standard library containers therefore makes NetBeans show sensible values as a result.

Follow the instructions on the gdb wiki to install the python pretty-printers for viewing STL containers: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

(Check to ensure the path was entered correctly inside `.gdbinit`; try entering the commands in python to ensure it all works)

This pretty-printing only works with g++ 4.7 (and above), however. Check to ensure the compiler version is adequate:

```
g++ --version
```

To install the latest version (for Linux Mint 13, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991401/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-2-on-linux-mint)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.7 c++-4.7
```

Update `gcc` and `g++` to point to the new 4.7 versions (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/26502)):

```
sudo su
rm /usr/bin/g++
rm /usr/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.7 /usr/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting them into `.gdbinit` file in the directory where your source is (or your home directory) and see if GDB picks them up.

Comment: Yes, but the question is: how to use them in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

The stl-views.gdb is quite old. GDB 7.x has a *much* better [mechanism](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524) for inspecting STL containers.

Comment: Can I connect it with NetBeans somehow?