# How to install GCC 4.7.2 on Linux Mint?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, linux-mint

I need to install the latest version of GCC on Linux Mint 13. I found some useful terminal commands for Ubuntu 12.04, but it seems that nothing similar for Mint exists on the Internet...

Edit: I solved the problem, so, in order to help everybody else, write these commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install g++-4.7 c++-4.7`

And everything works fine. :)

Answer (score 6):

I built it from source when I did this not too long ago.

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168947/how-to-upgrade-g-to-4-7-1), but I downloaded and extracted gcc 4.7.2 first instead of last and replaced steps 3 to 5 with running this script that comes with it (which does those steps for you):

`gcc-4.7.2/contribs/download_prerequisites`

You can download the gcc sources from one of the mirror sites: http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html

---

**Edit:** added the instructions in-post

1. Download and extract g++-4.7.2
2. $sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib m4
3. In order to compensate for insufficient path information, added this to .bashrc

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

   export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu export

   export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu export

   export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
4. Add these symlinks for the same reason:

   $sudo ln -s /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h /usr/include/gnu

   $sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/crti.o

   $sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/crt1.o

   $sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/crtn.o

   $sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmpc.so.3 /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3
5. run gcc-4.7.2/contribs/download_prerequisites
6. configure, make, make install

Answer (score 3):

To find a specific package type

```
apt-cache search "package"
```

In your case "gcc". Mine showed at least 40 different gnu compiler packages to choose from. The one it sounds like you want is gcc-4.7-base. Also you could update `apt-get` before searching.

```
sudo apt-get update
```